# Floating picture in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a picture that I've set to float on top and stay in the top right corner of the sheet as the user scrolls around.

I would like to change this, so that the picture still floats, but jumps back to the corner if the user has scrolled more than `X` amount of rows in either direction, and/or `Y` amount of column in either direction.

This will mean the picture moves around with the sheet for a while and then returns to the top corner once user scrolled 'enough'.

Code used for floating picture:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3")
        .Top = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Top
        .Left = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Left + ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - .Width - 15
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I wondering the last `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is typo...

Comment: In this case I think you want to detect if the visibleRange.Left is increased by a value of X or larger, and then update the place of the image.

Comment: just a suggestion, `application.ontime` to update the position on every 1 second instead of having to make a cell selection change